# 408 kubernetes google cloud client

Tags: node.js, docker, express, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud `kubernetes` and i want to push my `docker` image.

My image is hello-world project with node + express + google cloud client libray `@google-cloud/language`

You can find it on my github

https://github.com/innostarterkit/language

When I tried to push, i have this error

> The push refers to repository [eu.gcr.io/innovation-xxx/hello]
>   a419c4413fb0: Pushing
>   [==================================================>]  61.12MB/61.12MB
>   a5386aa0f20d: Pushing
>   [==================================================>]  75.97MB/75.97MB
>   8104e9470102: Pushed  2fdedebbc077: Layer already exists 
>   0804854a4553: Layer already exists  6bd4a62f5178: Layer already exists
>   9dfa40a0da3b: Layer already exists  error parsing HTTP 408 response
>   body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "\n\n  \n  \n 
>   Error 408 (Request Timeout)!!1\n  \n
>   *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7%
>   auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* >
>   body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px
>   no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0
>   22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a
>   img{border:0}@media screen and
>   (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
>   no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and
>   (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
>   no-repeat 0% 0%/100%
>   100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
>   0}}@media only screen and
>   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
>   no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100%
>   100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n 
>   \n  \n
>
> **408.** That’s an
>   error.\n
>
> Your client has taken too long to issue its
>   request.  That’s all we know.\n"

I used to push any project on my kubernetes but with google cloud client library, that doesn't work :(

However I don't have a proxy

Do you have some idea ?

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you perform some troubleshooting in order to capture any suspicious events generated from within your Docker [daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/).

There might be an option to include the `debug` flag in your docker command. Thus it may log some more significant events when you're pushing the docker images to the container repository:

`docker -l debug push eu.gcr.io/innovation-xxx/hello`

However, you can always switch Docker daemon `dockerd` to the debug mode:

- By adding appropriate `"debug": true` flag to `daemon.json` config file, the original path might be `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, of course docker service restart is required afterwards.
- You can also start the Docker daemon manually by adjusting it with the special `debug` flag:

Stop your current docker service:

`service docker stop`

Launch `dockerd` in debug mode:

`dockerd --debug`

Try to push the image to Google container [registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/) in a separate terminal window, inspecting the output for `dockerd`.

Do not forget to start docker service, once you finish debugging.